# Past Perfect in Future in the Past

Tags: conditional-constructions

I want to see how the below sentence will be in Future in the Past

**When you have finished your work by the morning, I will be very glad**

What if we add "He knew" making all of this Future in the Past

**He knew when you had finished your work by the morning, I would be very glad.**

Right?

Comment: Your original sentence isn't natural. It should be *When you have finished your work **in** the morning, I will be very glad.* Or *When you have finished your work **tomorrow** morning, I will be very glad.* To keep *by*, it should be *If you have finished your work by morning, I will be very glad.*

Comment: Given that, your addition of *he knew* is okay—although I personally would add *that* to it. (But it's optional.) Note, too, that you didn't ***only*** add *he knew*. You also changed *have* to *had* and *will* to *would*.

Comment: But why do we say: "I knew I would be glad" instead of "I knew I will be glad" but not "He knew that when I had finished my work by tomorrow morning I would be glad" instead of "he knew that when you have finished your work I will be very glad"?

Comment: Your comparison is wrong. We **do** say *he knew that when I had finished my work tomorrow morning I would be glad* instead of the other . . .

Comment: But you said just now that it wasn't natutal

Comment: First, I was talking about a different construction, one that didn't start off with *he knew*. Second, I was talking about the use of *by the morning*, not about the verb tenses. (*By the morning* will sound unnatural regardless of the verb tenses in these two versions of the sentence.)

Comment: "I knew If you had finished your work by the morning, I would be very glad" This way it should sound correct. Does it?

Comment: No. As I've been saying *by the morning* doesn't work. It should be just *by morning* or *in the morning.* Or maybe *this morning* in this sentence. (And, again, this has nothing to do with the verb tenses.)

Comment: Fine - "I knew If you had finished your work by morning, I would be very glad". The verb tenses? Isn't ir correct to use Past Perfect and Future Simple in the Past here?